# How can I create an array of handles / pointers to matrices in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, pointers

I have a bunch of related matrices of different sizes, and would like to be able to incrementally access them. Is there an easy way to create a vector of handles or pointers to these matrices in Matlab? Or is this not the way I am supposed to do it?

For example, here I want to assign to the vector indexed with i, which will be a handle to  the matrices of different size.

```
rows = [1:6];
columns = [10:2:20];
for i=1:6
    vector_of_pointers(i) = ones(rows(i),columns(i));
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array of Matrices in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466972/array-of-matrices-in-matlab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Matlab, there aren't really pointers.

Instead, you can collect the arrays in a cell array, like so

```
rows = [1:6];
columns = [10:2:20];
for i=1:6
    arrayOfArrays{i} = ones(rows(i),columns(i));
end
```

To access, say, array #3, you write `arrayOfArrays{3}`, and if you want its second row only, you write `arrayOfArrays{3}(2,:)`.

You can also create your array using [ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html)

```
arrayOfArrays = arrayfun(@(u,v)ones(u,v),rows,columns,'uniformOutput',false)
```