# Build an array of images in Matlab

Tags: arrays, image, matlab

I'm doing a Matlab project and I need to know how to build an array of images.
I need to have the ability to move through the array in a similar format as a C array with some kind of index.

I tried it with this:

```
images = [image1 image2 image3 image4 image5];
```

but I get this error:

> CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

I checked the `size(image)` method for every one of the images and all of them are from the same dimension.

What could be wrong or alternatively how I can do this in other way?

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array of Matrices in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466972/array-of-matrices-in-matlab)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two ways you can build an array of images:

#### 1. A 3D array

You catenate your images (all should be the same size) along the third dimension like so:

```
imgArray=cat(3,image1,image2,image3,...)
```

You can then access each individual image by indexing the third dimension. E.g.

```
image1=imgArray(:,:,1);
```

#### 2. A cell array

In this case, you group your images into a cell array, and each image is contained in its own cell.

```
imgCell={image1,image2,image3,...};
```

This is a good choice (the only choice) when your images are of different sizes. To access each individual image, you can index the cell as follows:

```
image1=imgCell{1};
```

Comment: Can the 3D array be used if the third dimension of the images are the rgb channels? **(rows, cols, chanels)**

Answer (score 4):

This code:

```
images = [image1 ... image5];
```

Is functionally equivalent to these statements:

```
images = horzcat(image1, ..., image5);
images = cat(2, image1, ..., image5);
```

You get the error because there's at least one dimension in your image[1-5] that is not the same.  The only dimension that's allowed to be a different size is the first argument to cat (so in this case the 2nd or columns dimension).

Comment: like I wrote above. I checked the size(image) method for every one of the images and all of them has different size but same dimension. so I don't think this is the case.

Comment: @Michael: It sounds like you're saying that the number of dimensions is the same but the sizes are different.  So just to clarify, the result of size(image) is exactly the same for every dimension but the 2nd? Edit: perhaps post the results of the size commands

Comment: thanks for your help, but yoda's answer is exactly what I needed. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try reshaping (`vector1 = reshape(image1, 1, size(image1,1)*size(image1,2))`) each image so that you get a vector and then put these vectors into your array like `images = [vector1; vector2; vector3; vector4; vector5]`