# Add cells in cell array of matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Code for creation of cell arrays taken from: 
[Array of Matrices in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466972/array-of-matrices-in-matlab/467042#467042)
[Thank you Hosam Aly!]

**The function is:**

```
function result = createArrays(nArrays, arraySize)
    result = cell(1, nArrays);
    for i = 1 : nArrays
        result{i} = zeros(arraySize);
    end
end
```

**My code:**

```
   a=createArrays(49,[9,9]);

    a{1}(1,1) = 0.01 + 1.*rand(1,1);
    a{1}(2,2) = 0.01 + 1.*rand(1,1);
    a{1}(3,3) = 0.01 + 1.*rand(1,1);
    a{1}(4,4) = 0.01 + 1.*rand(1,1);
    a{1}(5,5) = 0.01 + 1.*rand(1,1);
    a{1}(6,6) = 0.01 + 1.*rand(1,1);
    a{1}(7,7) = 0.01 + 1.*rand(1,1);
    a{1}(8,8) = 0.01 + 1.*rand(1,1);
    a{1}(9,9) = 0.01 + 1.*rand(1,1);
```

I cannot use **a{:}(1,1)** to refer to all matrices. Matlab finds using { } an unexpected parenthesis when using loops.

I'd like to keep the format as above for the diagonal. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing I can see is just to loop through all your cells:

```
for i = 1:49
 a{i}(1,1) = ...
end
```

But why use cells when you can just do a 3D matrix?

```
a = zeros(49,9,9);

a(:,2,2) = something
```

Comment: The rest of my code requires matrices to be stored in a cell array. The first part of your answer works, thanks!

Comment: ok, but the second way is much faster if speed becomes a factor someday

Answer (score 1):

To fill diagonal elements you don't have to do it one by one. use [EYE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eye.html) function instead.

```
c1 = 1;
c2 = 0.01;
for i = 1:numel(a)
    a{i} = eye(size(a{i}) * c1 + c2;
end
```

Comment: Ah yes I understand. It's just that each diagonal element will be the result of different equations. Thanks for your advice though!