# Array of matrices with different size in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Is it possible in Matlab to create array of matrices which have different size.
For example

```
Array_Mat(:,:,1) = zeros(3);
Array_Mat(:,:,2) = zeros(4);
```

This gives error. How I can make array of matrices then?

Comment: Likely a [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466972/array-of-matrices-in-matlab).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use cells.

```
>> a{1}=[1 2 ;3 4]

a = 

    [2x2 double]

>> a{2}=zeros(4)

a = 

    [2x2 double]    [4x4 double]

>> a{1}(2,1)

ans =

     3

>> a{2}(3,4)

ans =

     0
```

Comment: How fast is this method in compare to regular one for large matrices?

Comment: @Hesam, I am not sure, you may want to try the cells vs 3-D matrices, i.e. try a{1}=randn(100,100) for a{1} up to a{1000} vs a=randn(100,100,1000).