# Matlab: store array in matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have many array (`n*1` dimension), how can I do something like

```
matrix = [];
for i = 1:5
  for j =1:5
    matrix (i,j) = zeros(n,1); % store a given array to a cell of a matrix 
  end
end
```

I find [Array of Matrices in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466972/array-of-matrices-in-matlab)
But this is store matrices into array, not the otherwise.

Comment: Does `n` change between iterations?

Comment: @kkuilla Well...I want to know both cases(change and not change).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ying Xiong's suggestion is what you want if the vectors are of different lengths. But assuming the number of elements is constant (which they seem to be) you may also use a 3-dimensional array, where each `(i,j)` element contains a vector in the third dimension, like this:

```
rows = 5; cols = 5; n = 10;     %// Dimensions
matrix = zeros(rows, cols, n);  %// Initialize matrix
vector = 1:n;                   %// Just an example    
for ii = 1:rows                 %// Bad practice to use i as a variable name 
   for jj = 1:cols              %// Bad practice to use j as a variable name
      matrix(ii,jj,:) = vector; %// Assignment
   end
end
```

Now each index `(i,j)` contains the vectors you want, for instance:

```
squeeze(matrix(1,1,:))
ans =
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
    10
```

Having all values in a single matrix can be a good thing if you want to do similar operations on all elements, as vectorized approaches are usually very fast in MATLAB. You might want to check out [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/permute.html), [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and functions like [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).

Note that you might be able to vectorize the loops, but without knowing the specifics, that's impossible to know.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html?refresh=true).

```
n = 10;
matrix = cell(5,5);
for i = 1:5
  for j = 1:5
    matrix{i,j} = zeros(n,1);
  end
end
```