# mathematical operation (Sum) on array elements

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to sum elements of array which every element is a matrix.

I wrote below but not working:

```
AA={[1 2;3 4],[5 6;7 8]}
i=1:2;
sum(AA{i})
```

Comment: What result would you expect to get for this example?

Comment: I want [6 8;10 12] @gnovice

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using a cell array?  Why not a 3D array and sum in the third dimension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are wanting to perform operations across a set of 2-D matrices, **all of which are the same size** (and not too huge), it's easiest to store them as a 3-D matrix instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/466972/52738) for discussion/examples.

If you already have your matrices in a cell array, as in your example, you can concatenate them into a 3-D matrix using [`cat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) and sum across the third dimension without a for loop using [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html):

```
mat = sum(cat(3, AA{:}), 3);
```