# How to create a k matrix according to an array of indices using matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I need to create `k` matrix with diferent numbers of rows in MatLab. How can I do it?

Supose that I have `k=5` and that I have `2` matrix, like that ones (The matrix `Mpop` can be seen as any matrix)

```
Mpop = 
    0.9284    0.9299  -46.3239    1.2597   15.1842   21.8344   68.1583
   -0.9948   -2.0102  -44.9439    1.7241   15.7423   38.2638   83.2077
    1.1801   -0.9930  -41.8621    3.5203   14.3528   92.4522  134.3142
    0.8557   -0.8754  -41.7513    2.7033   13.9570   67.2608  109.0121
    1.1149    1.9312  -41.6132    2.6042   14.7964   66.1055  107.7187
    1.1153    0.1656  -41.2766    4.4585   13.8216  120.1216  161.3983
   -1.1358   -1.9447  -40.9061    1.9565   14.6642   47.1186   88.0247
    0.0062   -0.2411  -40.4918    1.5405   13.8066   33.3358   73.8276
   -0.1984   -1.1021  -39.9417    1.2500   13.6128   24.7840   64.7256
    0.0876   -0.2284  -39.8141    2.2970   13.4819   56.0590   95.8732
```

and (`IDX` is a vector with values `1` to `k`)

```
IDX = 
     3
     4
     1
     3
     2
     3
     4
     5
     3
     4
```

So, if line `i` of `IDX` is equal to `1`, I need to put the line `i` of `Mpop` in matrix `Mpop1`, in the same way, if line `i` of `IDX` is equal to `2`, I need to put the line `i` of `Mpop` in matrix `Mpop2`, etc.

I can do it in this way

```
Mpop1 = zeros(10,7);
Mpop2 = zeros(10,7);
Mpop3 = zeros(10,7);
Mpop4 = zeros(10,7);
Mpop5 = zeros(10,7);

    for i=1:npop
        if IDX(i,1)==1
            Mpop1(i,:) = Mpop(i,:)
        elseif IDX(i)==2
            Mpop2(i,:) = Mpop(i,:)
        elseif IDX(i)==3
            Mpop3(i,:) = Mpop(i,:)
        elseif IDX(i)==4
            Mpop4(i,:) = Mpop(i,:)
        else IDX(i)==5
            Mpop5(i,:) = Mpop(i,:)
        end
    end
Mpop1 = Mpop1(all(Mpop1,2),:)
Mpop2 = Mpop2(all(Mpop2,2),:)
Mpop3 = Mpop3(all(Mpop3,2),:)
Mpop4 = Mpop4(all(Mpop4,2),:)
Mpop5 = Mpop5(all(Mpop5,2),:)
```

but it is not good because `K` can be diferent from `5`.

So, how can I do it if I have any value of `K`?

Answer (score 2):

It would be a bad idea to create those 5 matrices. Rather use a cell array and use its indexes to access/use a particular matrix. Here is a  solution using 2 loops:

```
numIDX = numel(IDX);            %Number of elements of IDX

tmp = cell(k,numIDX);           %Pre-allocation
for ii=1:numIDX
    tmp{IDX(ii),ii}=Mpop(ii,:); %Converted the if-else conditions into a single line
end

req = cell(k,1);                %Pre-allocation of the required cell
for jj=1:k
   req{jj}=vertcat(tmp{jj,:});  %vertically concatenating/ removing the empty cells of tmp
end
```

Now use the indices of this cell array to access `Mpop1`, `Mpop2`, `Mpop3`, `Mpop4`, and `Mpop5` i.e. with `req{1}`, `req{2}`, `req{3}`, `req{4}`, and `req{5}` respectively.

Comment: Why are dynamic variables/matrices a bad idea? Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467029/how-to-put-these-images-together/32467170#32467170 Also don't use `i` and `j` as variable names. Read here why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab

Comment: Having said that, if you really want those matrices separately, in the 2nd `for` loop, use this line instead: `assignin('base',['Mpop',num2str(jj)],vertcat(tmp{jj,:}));`

Answer (score 1):

If your matrixes have different names, there isn't much else you can do by working this way. A good way to achieve this, however, would probably be to use cell arrays (see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/467042/5776736) about them). Basically, all your matrixes will be in a single variable, and you can select the right matrix with an index, which would be `IDX(i)` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

As [stated by Sardar Usama](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43968214/2586922), it's better use a cell array rather than creating dynamic variables.

Here's another way to create that cell array without loops, using the [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) function:

```
result = accumarray(IDX, (1:numel(IDX)).', [], @(x){Mpop(sort(x),:)})
```

This splits the integers from `1` to `numel(IDX)` in groups as determined by the values in `IDX`; applies those indices into the original matrix `Mpop`; and packs the resulting submatrices in a cell array.

Comment: How I will access `Mpop1`, `Mpop2`, etc in this case?

Comment: @ElcioSilveira Just like as in my answer. `result{1}`, `result{2}`, ...

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by juef, using cell arrays is the way to go:

```
% define the length of the arrays/matrices
nID = max(IDX);
npop = length(IDX);

% allocate memory
Mpops = cell(nID, 1);
[Mpops{:}] = deal(zeros(10,7));

% fill the matrices
for i=1:npop
    Mpops{IDX(i)}(i, :) = Mpop(i,:);
end

% remove empty rows
for i=1:nID
    Mpops{i} = Mpops{i}(all(Mpops{i},2),:);
end
```